# Can't remove empty values from multi-dimensional array PHP

Tags: php

My multi-dimensional array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2010-12-03
        [1] => 0
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2010-12-10
        [1] => 486
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Bob
                        [1] => Lucy
                        [2] => 54
                        [3] => Y
                        [4] => PC1Clean
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Jo
                        [1] => Mary
                        [2] => 432
                        [3] => Y
                        [4] => PC2Bar
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 
                        [4] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

I've tried `array_filter` and different loop iterations to remove the `zero`/`null` values, such as

```
function removeElementWithValue($array, $key, $value) {
    foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray) {
        if($subArray[$key] == $value) {
            unset($array[$subKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to be working.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think it's an issue with the scope of the variable `$array`.

Comment: you need to pass reference to your function, otherwise you are not unsetting from the original array

Comment: http://rogerpadilla.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/remove-empty-items-from-array/

Answer (score 3):

You need to recursively call your remove function. (*Call the function for every sub-value in the array, and then the function will call itself for every sub-sub-value etc. automatically until it can't get any further down the tree*).

Here's a quickly made (untested) function that should remove all empty values (including arrays, if they're empty):

```
function removeEmptyElements($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if (empty($value)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        } else if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = removeEmptyElements($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: True, but the array should also be passed by reference. Otherwise, the changes only affect the local copy.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Considering that the function has `return $array`, I thought it was quite obvious that you just call it by using `$array = removeEmptyElements($array);`?

Comment: Ah, you are right. That is a change from the OP's original manner of calling the function, so it may be worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is a bit too late, but here it is:

```
$array = array( // array with examples
    array('123',' 456', array(123, null)),
    array('', null, '123'),
    123,
    234,
    0,
    null,
); 

$filterEmptyValues = function($val) use (&$filterEmptyValues) {
    foreach($val as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            if (!$value) unset($val[$key]);
        }
        else $val[$key] = call_user_func($filterEmptyValues, $value);
    }
    return $val;
};


$array = $filterEmptyValues($array) ;

print_r($array);
```